# ОШИБКА: INSERT содержит больше целевых столбцов, чем выражений

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть таблица Animal, в которую я ввожу значения, но почему-то при вводе значение появляется ОШИБКА:  INSERT содержит больше целевых столбцов, чем выражений. Указатель показывает на description, хотя ошибок в синтаксисе нет. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём ошибка может быть. Я буду ооооооочень благодарен за помощь

```
CREATE TABLE Animal
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    animalType VARCHAR(50),
    kingColor VARCHAR(50),
    size INT,
    hair VARCHAR(50),
    ears VARCHAR(50),
    tail VARCHAR(50),
    description VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Animal (animalType, kingColor, size, hair, ears, tail, description)
VALUES 
('Собака', 'Белая', 143, 'Кудрявые', 'Маленькие', 'Пушистый'),
('Кошка', 'Рыжая', 67, 'Прямые', 'Короткий'),
('Обезьяна', 'Корничевая', 121, 'Нет'),
('Орёл', 'Светло-корничевый', 102, 'Шерстянные', 'Маленькие');
```

Comment: что же, слова "содержит больше столбцов, чем" вас не наталкивает совсем ни на какие мысли?)) что-то посчитать например

Comment: В том то и проблем, что в таблице 7 основных полей, без автоинкремента и в INSERT INTO 7 полей я указываю

Comment: тааак..хорошо..... а ещё где должно быть 7 помимо секции указания полей?

Comment: Понял, а как мне указать нулевые значения?
'', NULL - не работают(

Comment: Ну вообще при создании таблицы по умолчанию NULL. Так что скорее всего ты не так  инсертишь NULL. Без примера как ты это делаешь  и какую ошибку выдаёт - ничего сказать нельзя

Comment: Ввожу строку: ('Собака', 'Белая', 143, 'Кудрявые', 'Маленькие', 'Пушистый', NULL),
ОШИБКА:  INSERT содержит больше выражений, чем целевых столбцов
Указатель на NULL

Comment: а для остальных: кошки, обезъяны и орла, тоже указали null и у них по 7 значений?

Comment: Да, у собаки, кошки, орла, обезьяны также null указывал и '', результата не дало

Comment: Покажите **полный свой запрос** включая все строки...скорее всего вы добираете до 7  .............https://www.db-fiddle.com/ вот тут например  можно сделать

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bFoBRdqUbNf9SUM8jM1JDR/0

Comment: ну правильно.......description то куда потерялся?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ошибку, оказывается в пустых полях нужно указывать значение NULL
Отдельная благодарность Алексей Шиманский

```
CREATE TABLE Animal
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    animalType VARCHAR(50),
    kingColor VARCHAR(50),
    size INT,
    hair VARCHAR(50),
    ears VARCHAR(50),
    tail VARCHAR(50),
    description VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Animal (animalType, kingColor, size, hair, ears, tail, description)
VALUES 
('Собака', 'Белая', 143, 'Кудрявые', 'Маленькие', 'Пушистый', NULL),
('Кошка', 'Рыжая', 67, 'Прямые', 'Короткий', NULL, NULL),
('Обезьяна', 'Корничевая', 121, 'Нет', NULL, NULL, NULL),
('Орёл', 'Светло-корничевый', 102, 'Шерстянные', 'Маленькие', NULL, NULL);
```